# How can I have Google Spreadsheet display all dates as MM/DD rather than MM/D?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, formulas

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to get Google Spreadsheet to always display date as MM/DD.  Currently for the first 9 days of the month it displays MM/D (12/4) rather than MM/DD (12/04).  There does not seem to be a option to set this under formatting.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Far from ideal, but if you date is in A1 then:

```
=month(A1)&"/"&if(day(A1)<10,"0"&day(A1),day(A1))
```

might serve.

Comment: Wow that's awesome, how can I have that apply to an entire column rather than just a cell?  As all my entries for dates are in column A